# Why I cannot get the right path with NSURL (swift)

Tags: cocoa, swift, nsurl, nsopenpanel

[image: debug info]

It is the situation when I use

```
NSOpenPanel
```

and

```
 NSURL
```

to get a open file path string coding with Swift.
The path should be

```
"/Users/yy/Downloads/CHS16.FON"
```

but I got something like

```
"p\xab\xe2w\xff\x7f"
```

, and I don't know why.

p.s. Top left hollow circle is a small bug too, actually I have connected the action with a button.

Answer (score 0):

NSOpenPanel return a NSURL, fileHandleForReadingAtPath need a String, i've solve this with this function and it works for me :

```
func nsurlToString (nsurlInit:NSURL) -> String {
    var nsurlProperty:NSURL = nsurlInit
    var urlString:String = nsurlProperty.absoluteString!
    urlString.removeRange(urlString.startIndex..<advance(urlString.startIndex, +7))
    return urlString
 }
```